# Set tabulation size when function's parameters are written on multiple lines

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I need to respect a coding style with 4 spaces tabulations and I want to fit with the 80 columns rule. I get then the case where some function need their parameters written on several line :

```
int very_long_function_name (int long_param_name_1, int long_param_name_2)
```

I want it to be changed into

```
int very_long_function_name (int long_param_name_1,
    int long_param_name_2)
```

But when I press <kbd>=</kbd> to autoindent, I get

```
int very_long_function_name (int long_param_name_1,
        int long_param_name_2)
```

I set these values in my .vimrc :

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: This is controlled by the `cinoptions` option, you should have a look at [`:h 'cinoptions'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cinoptions%27) and more precisely at [`:h cinoptions-values`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#cinoptions%2Dvalues) and [`:h cino-(`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#cino-%28).

Comment: Thank you @statox ! I solved my problem by setting adding `cinoptions=(4,W4`. These options are exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Glad I could help, I made it an answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`:h cinoptions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cinoptions%27) you read:

```
The 'cinoptions' affect the way 'cindent' reindents lines in a C program.
See cinoptions-values for the values of this option
```

From [`:h cinoptions-values`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#cinoptions%2Dvalues):

```
The 'cinoptions' option sets how Vim performs indentation.  The value after
the option character can be one of these (N is any number):
    N   indent N spaces
    -N  indent N spaces to the left
    Ns  N times 'shiftwidth' spaces
    -Ns N times 'shiftwidth' spaces to the left
```

And finally [`:h cino-(`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#cino%2D%28) and [`:h cino-W`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#cino%2DW) tell us that `set cino=(` defines the behavior that the indentation should follow when it handles text between some parentheses.

Here `set cinoptions=(4,W4` tells vim:

- When in unclosed parentheses, indent N characters from the with the unclosed parentheses.
- When in unclosed parentheses and the unclosed parentheses is the last non-white character in its line and it is not the closing parentheses, indent the following line N characters relative to the outer context (i.e. start of the line or the next unclosed parentheses).

Which does the trick as @Meinew noted in the comments.